# Rails: get to parent resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I got a config/routes.rb file like this:

```
  map.resources :categories, :shallow => true do |cat|
    cat.resources :entries,  :member => {:yes => :post, :no => :post }
  end
```

My goal is use yes and no as buttons that modify my entries (it is like a game, and yes and no are answers to the entries).

I would like that when I click on yes or no I will go back to category/:category_id/entries , because there is where I have the pretty layout, etc.

The problem is that I got to the yes method from entries/:entry_id So I lost the category id this entry is in and I dont know how to get a link to the category.

I guess I can try without using :shallow parameter so I got the full path but I am probably going to go further in the hierarqui (entries may have comments) and I want to learn with this simple problem how to manage this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your entries are subresources of your categories, then there is probably a parent-child relationship between the models, right?  If so, then you can use:

```
redirect_to category_entries_path(@entry.category)
```

in your `yes` and `no` methods.

Comment: It worked perfectly.
I am still overwhelmed by the amount of things rails do in programmers behalf. 
Didn't know that belongs_to in the model would create @entry.category 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your button, you can specify the category like so:

```
link_to "Yes", yes_entry([@category, Entry.new]), :method => :post
```

I'm not sure if it works though, otherwise you could try:

```
link_to "Yes", yes_entry(Entry.new, :category_id => @category), :method => :post
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [resource_controller](http://jamesgolick.com/resource_controller)? I didn't work with :shallow option (and this solution is probably without it), but resource_controller supports some kind of polymorphic resources (you can have url's like: /entries, /category/3/entries, /whatever/12/entries etc). Then you can generate url to entries with this:

```
<%= link_to 'Entries', collection_path %>
```

But in case of your 'yes' and 'no' methods, you only need to add:

```
redirect_to collection_path
```

in response to 'yes' and 'no' actions.